# Hashicorp Vault - Unable to Update Expired Secret of Azure App Registration

Tags: azure-keyvault, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to update an expired Secret of an Azure App Registration that is linked to Azure Key Vault, and plan to generate a root token for this operation since I am unable to login via OIDC.

I've tried this guide "[Generate Root Tokens Using Unseal Keys](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/operations/generate-root)" which generates the root token using Shamir's Secret Sharing.

The final user during the root token generation is getting this error msg

```
* root generation aborted: unable to authenticate: recovery key verification failed: failed to decrypt encrypted stored keys: azure.BearerAuthorizer#WithAuthorization: Failed to refresh the Token for request to https://<redacted azure key vault endpoint>: StatusCode=401 -- Original Error: adal: Refresh request failed. Status Code = '401'. Response body: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000222: The provided client secret keys for app '<redacted>' are expired. Visit the Azure portal to create new keys for your app: https://aka.ms/NewClientSecret, or consider using certificate credentials for added security...
```

How am I supposed to update the expired secret without Hashicorp Vault having to talk to Azure Key Vault?

Comment: @Sridevi I can update (create new client secret) the Azure app registration but I need to now update Hashicorp Vault with the new client secret which I cannot seem to do.